Authentication state does not change in Blazor .NET 8
I have Blazor web assembly application on .NET 8. I tried to implement custom authentication in it, but my code doesn't work. Elements located in the block [Authorized] are not displayed.
In my solution, I have 3 projects: Server, Client, Shared.
Server.Program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    o.SaveToken = true;
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JwtAuthenticationManager.JWT_SECURITY_KEY)),
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<UserAccountService>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();

Client.Program.cs
uilder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

Client.CustomAuthenticationStateProvider.cs
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly ISessionStorageService _sessionStorage;
    private ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(ISessionStorageService sessionStorage)
    {
        _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
    }
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var userSession = await _sessionStorage.ReadEncryptedItemAsync<UserSession>("userSession");
            if (userSession == null)
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,userSession.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,userSession.Id.ToString())
            }, "JwtAuth"));
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
        }
        catch 
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
        }

    }
     public async Task UpdateAuthenticationState(UserSession? userSession)
     {
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;
        if (userSession != null)
        {
            claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,userSession.Id.ToString())
            }));
            userSession.ExpiryTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(userSession.ExpiresIn);
            await _sessionStorage.SaveItemEncryptedAsync("UserSession", userSession);
        }
        else
        {
            claimsPrincipal = _anonymous;
            await _sessionStorage.RemoveItemAsync("UserSession");
        }
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
     }
    public async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            var userSession = await _sessionStorage.ReadEncryptedItemAsync<UserSession>("UserSession");
            if ( userSession != null && DateTime.Now< userSession.ExpiryTimeStamp)
                result = userSession.Token;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        return result;
    }
}

I have an assumption that the problems are due to the fact that the provider is registered in both projects, but I don't know how to fix it. If I remove the provider registration from the server project, the application does not start.

Could you please verify if user sesssion and token are correctly retrieved? I tested with custom state provider based on https://medium.com/@shahriyarali08/authentication-and-role-based-authorization-in-blazor-wasm-using-jwt-and-7bcc12317ea  and the services registration only needed in client program. According to your code, your state is updated based on the logic of your login action, could you offer more details. I cannot reproduce your problem, .net8 blazor wasm template doesn't contain shared file, how did you construct your project?

posted the project on github: https://github.com/GorbanArseny/test
I'm using a template Blazor WebApp with Fluent UI. I added the Shared project myself.

I tested with your code and I found that your provider lacked httpclient to midify DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization, which makes the state.isAuthenticated false. Meanwhile the [CascadingParameter] of authenticationState is needed too. Please check the code and test. Your structure looks right , but please simplify it https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/  and check the differences.
